# Gfx.WaitForPresentOnGfxThread long waiting

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, profiler

as I khow Gfx.WaitForPresentOnGfxThread wait for GPU to run some stuffs.
I have a scene with around 30k tris that one character and 3 ai simply collect some collectables. calculations are simple and don't eat up CPU and GPU. but my profiler is weird. here is my profiler.
[image]

something confused me. GPU takes 18.54ms and CPU takes 33.08ms thus CPU shouldn't wait for GPU. as we see in picture render thread start it's work after about 23.5ms from when the current frame started.
maybe it's because GPU hasn't done it's work.
do my results is correct?
another question is why GPU takes so much time for rendering about 30k tris?
another picture from rendering and GPU in profiler
[image]

Comment: In general this means your GPU is doing too much and he CPU has to wait for it  .. see e.g. https://forum.unity.com/threads/gfx-waitforpresentongfxthread.731327 ... is it possible you are using some compute shaders for calculation or similar .. like what/how exactly does this AI do?

Comment: even in frame debugger I see some compute shader for my SkinMeshRender but in my GPU profiler I can see  all of PostLateUpdate.UpdateAllSkinnedMeshed get just 0.2 percent of whole proccess on GPU. camera.render eat up Process with 61.9 percent.

Comment: as we see in first image does 18ms for GPU take place before render thread in the current frame? Maybe this assumption be correct because most of Gfx.WaitForPresentOnGfxThread accured before starting render thread in this frame. whit this assumption even with a short  GPU time in a frame we may have a big cpu time thus we have a 30 frame game.